# Sails has no method 'subscribeToFirehose'

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, sails.js

I am trying to create the Firehose functionality as defined in the documentation [here](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/reference/websockets/sails.sockets/sails.sockets.subscribeToFirehose.html). It seems straight-fowards (code follows) but it just keeps giving an error:

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'subscribeToFirehose'
```

Controller:

```
module.exports = {

    /**
     * `UserController.index()`
     */
    index: function (req, res) {
        if (!req.isSocket) return res.badRequest();

        sails.sockets.subscribeToFirehose(req.socket);

        // sails.sockets.subscribeToFirehose(req.socket);
        return res.ok();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, sorry, that should be removed from the docs.  If you're using v0.11, the firehose has been deprecated.  Read all about it in the [migration guide](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/changelog/0.11).

Comment: @sgress454 can you create an issue/PR for this?